# jquery using i18n values programmatically

Tags: jquery, i18next

I have i18 file for multilanguage, I can use i18 variables inside html elements thats fine
`<p hidden id="pcheckinfo" data-i18n="messages.mymessage"></p>` for constant i18 values.

But after some interaction by user activities, I need to edit text inside this element...

For expample:

```
var checkDate = new Date();
    $("#pcheckinfo").hide().empty().append("<i class='ace-icon fa fa-info'></i> There is new updates you can install. Date: " + checkDate).show(500);
```

Is there way doing like this:

```
$("#pcheckinfo").hide().empty().append("<i class='ace-icon fa fa-info'></i> 
[html]messages.randommessage" + checkDate).show(500);
```

What do you suggest ? (ver: i18next-1.11.1.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this; add a span with the tag `data-i18n="key"` of the value you want to be showed.

```
$("#pcheckinfo").hide().empty().append("<i class='ace-icon fa fa-info'></i><span data-i18n='messages.randommessage'></span>" + checkDate).show(500);
```